# d3 how to add a point to a chart using its coordinate space

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a line-chart created with d3.js which shows two intersecting graphs (series of data-points). The intersection position gets calculated via javascript by using a lineIntersection-Algorithm and returns an x/y-object. I would like to create a circle at this position or a vertical line to show the break-even which gets visualized with this intersection.

Using d3 I wrote the following function to add a svg-circle to the chart:

```
 d3.select('.nv-lineChart').append('circle')
   .attr("cx", intersection.x)
   .attr("cy", intersection.y)
   .attr("r", 5.5)
   .style("fill", "white")
   .style("stroke", "black");
```

The problem is: the intersection coordinates need to be applied to the line-chart's coordinate-space.
I have no real clue how to do that - the d3 documentation is not really helpful for this.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Can you post the full code that shows how you generate the lines? You should be able to append the circle inside the line group rather than the main svg container but without the code its difficult to say.

Comment: If you have a line chart then you probably have axes and if you have axes then you have scales.  Probably the scales are called `x` and `y`.  If so, then you can do `x(intersection.x)` for example.  This assumes that the `.nv-linechart` element also contains the line (so the margins etc are already accounted for.

Comment: You should be able to get the scales with e.g. `chart.xAxis.scale()` I think.

Comment: Ok. axis.scale() did the trick.
By using axis.scale(value)  you can convert the value to the axis-coordinate system.